# Access Object's "this" in another object's foreach function?

Tags: javascript, foreach, this

```
function Test(){
    this.update = function(entity){
              entity.forEach(function(enemy) {
                    this.checkHit(enemy);
                });
        }

        this.checkHit = function(entity){
                console.log("worked!");
        }

}
```

How can I call Test's this.checkHit function, and pass it the current value in the entity's foreach loop?

Current code gives "this.checkHit" is not a function.

Comment: `var that = this;` ..........

Comment: check `console.log(this)` and do changes as suggested by @zerkms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about old browsers - which seems to be the case since you're using `forEach` - you could use `bind` (also I assume that you're doing `new Test()` somewhere) :

```
entity.forEach(function (enemy) {
    this.checkHit(enemy);
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `this` in a normal variable. `self` is commonly used

```
function Test(){
    var self = this;
    this.update = function(entity){
              entity.forEach(function(enemy) {
                    self.checkHit(enemy);
                });
        }

        this.checkHit = function(entity){
                console.log("worked!");
        }

}
```